# Performance benefit of MySql Collation

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, collation, utf8mb4

Is there any grate performance benefit(s) for setting Collation for mysql database or let the database engine use the default Collation? 
Thanks.

Comment: One does not set the collation for performance purposes.  One sets the collation for functionality.

Comment: Collation settings affect sorting behaviour for example. Performance should not be considered here.

Comment: So Collation affects how ORDER BY works?

Comment: yes, it can. e.g. utf8_general_bin doesn't make a difference if the chars are uppercase or lowercase.  you use collation for the type of chars you want to store. maybe you saw a website in the past which couldn't display the german üöä or some frensh èéâ or other chars that don't belong to the 'english' keyboard. then the database admin choosed the wrong collation.

Comment: Is there a universal Collation in relation to the example cited by Kagome that supports multi-language or can Collation be used at query level?

Comment: @Kagome - `utf8_bin` is the case _sensitive_ collation.  `üöä` is undisplayable if the _charset_ is wrong collation is _not_ relevant.

Comment: `utf8mb4` handles all languages.  (`utf8` comes close.)  `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` is the best for collation in that it 'correctly' handles various single-character and multi-character encodings for characters in most languages.

Comment: You _can_ apply a different collation to a column or `WHERE` or `ORDER BY`.  Please provide an example for discussion.